# QML: How to place Repeater on top of existing Repeater?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

As in the title: I need to place repeater on top of existing one. Actually I mean any place in that - covering previous one elements, cause then I have to control second repeater elements using keyboard (it would be game with Timer)

I have tried use anchors, and it doesn't work.
I always have the second repeater exactly behind previous one elements.

BTW I have issue with all anchors in code below - it does not work as I am expecting. What am I doing wrong?
Any idea, please ?

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    property int wi: 640
    property int he: 500
    width: wi
    height: he
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Game")

    Rectangle {
        id: gameWindow
        width: wi/1.6
        height: he
        anchors.right: parent
        visible: true
        color: "black"
        clip: true

        Grid {
            id: gameGrid
            columns: 25
            spacing: 0
            rows: 32

            Repeater {
                model: 600
                anchors.fill: parent

                Rectangle {
                    width: wi/40 ; height: 20
                    border.width: 2
                    color: "grey"
                }
            }

            Repeater {
                model: 10
                anchors.fill: top

                Rectangle {
                    width: wi/40 ; height: 20
                    border.width: 1
                    color: "red"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put both `Repeater` in the same `Grid` which will layout the items of both in the same `Grid`. To have the items of the repeaters stacked on top of each other you need to create another `Grid` on top of the other with the same property values and size so they align.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    property int wi: 640
    property int he: 500
    width: wi
    height: he
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Game")

    Rectangle {
        id: gameWindow
        width: wi/1.6
        height: he
        anchors.right: parent.right
        visible: true
        color: "black"
        clip: true

        Grid {
            id: gameGrid
            columns: 25
            spacing: 0
            rows: 32
            anchors.fill: parent

            Repeater {
                model: 600

                Rectangle {
                    width: wi/40
                    height: 20
                    border.width: 2
                    color: "grey"
                }
            }
        }

        Grid {
            columns: gameGrid.columns
            spacing: gameGrid.spacing
            rows: gameGrid.rows
            anchors.fill: gameGrid

            Repeater {
                model: 10

                Rectangle {
                    width: wi/40
                    height: 20
                    border.width: 1
                    color: "red"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

About the anchors, you used the convenience `anchors.fill` with an anchor line `top` which isn't working. Have another look at [Positioning with Anchors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html).

> There are also some convenience anchors. anchors.fill is a convenience
> that is the same as setting the left,right,top and bottom anchors to
> the left,right,top and bottom of the target item. anchors.centerIn is
> another convenience anchor, and is the same as setting the
> verticalCenter and horizontalCenter anchors to the verticalCenter and
> horizontalCenter of the target item.

`anchors.right: parent` won't work, because you need to specify a anchor line, e.g. `parent.right`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @iam_peter. Of course I took another look at anchors. I still don't understand how coordinates work inside a Repeater. I have put the first element in expected place, unfortunately I couldn't set that inside Repeater, so I have set this inside Rectangle in Repeater. Now the issue is that x/y coordinates don't work. I tried to use anchors as well, in this case all Repeater elements are placed in one Grid element. Also using "index" in coordinates does not work. I spent 2 weeks on learning QML, it looks so simple, but reality turns out to be more difficult than expectations

Comment: I don't understand the issue or what you're trying to solve. Could you  create a new question that shows the problem you're facing?

Comment: Okay. I'll show it in another question